# Manually change caption label in subfig

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions, subfloats

In the example:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{subfig}

  \begin{document}


  \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\label{first}
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo}
  }
  \subfloat[]{\label{second}
  \includegraphics[width=1cm]{logo}
  }
  \caption{
  Some label referring to
  \protect\subref{first}.
  }
  \end{figure}


  \end{document}
```

I would like to manually label e.g. the second figure with a label like (ii-z) instead of (b). Note that I do not want it to be automatically labelled and \subfig* does not seem to help.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Insert a redefinition of `\thesubfigure` at the appropriate location:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \subfloat[]{\label{first}
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
  }
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{ii-z}% New fixed/manual numbering
  \subfloat[]{\label{second}
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-b}
  }
  \caption{Some label referring to~\protect\subref{first} and~\protect\subref{second}.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```